# C# Program which cannot run/access a local SQL Server database on another PC (Error 52)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, exception

This is a very tricky specific problem so I will try my best to describe it in its entirety.

I created a program in C# and it uses a Local DB (in Visual Studio 2019). When I right click on my `.mdf` file and click modify connection the data source is "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)". The program works and runs fine on my PC with no issues. I built the program with a release configuration so I could put it on my fathers PC for him to run.

The following error appears:

[error which appeared on his machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVk8k.jpg)

So after seeing that error, I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express on his machine (link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/details.aspx?id=101064) thinking that would solve the issue. Sadly, it has not. I have been trying to figure this out by looking for hours on end by looking through SQL Server configuration on his PC and trying to enable stuff but I have no luck. Does anybody know what I can do to run this program on his PC/other PCs?

As stated earlier, this is a localDB, so it should work without any connection to the internet. I know that means our databases would have different data. I don't want to his PC to access my DB and vice versa. I looked on here trying some suggestions from various threads but I didn't get anywhere. Here is my connection string in the `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="locdb"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\userScores.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

If I am missing any critical information which is needed please let me know as I want to solve this.

Comment: The connection string you have connects to SQL Server Express **LocalDB** - so you need to download and install that version of SQL Server - not the "regular" Express edition. Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This was the issue, I downloaded the regular edition and did the regular install without going to the extra media and specifically selecting the local db radio button. I love you. This should be the main/big answer. This could save a lot of people so much time so you should make this a bigger answer with a trophy. I am too new to upvote this, but I really think this could help out a lot of people who had the same issue I was having (error 52) because they probably did the same thing I did in terms of installing the full package and not a specific part of it.

Comment: You're welcome, Renee! Glad to be able to help. You can show your appreciation by [**accepting this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string you have connects to SQL Server Express **LocalDB** - not the "regular" Express edition (which would default to a `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance name).

So you need to download and install that version of SQL Server - . Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15 and get the bits from the appropriate download link and install them.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=name ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass"